# How do I correctly import and use a classes inside of a package in python

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to correctly use import in a package and after reading several answer I am not sure if I am doing it right. For me it's still a bit confusing

Assuming I have the following file structure, running `main.py` works but I can not compile foo.py:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_lib'

Is there a better way to create the needed dependencies?

```
main.py
test_lib
├── __init__.py (empty)
├── foo.py
└── bar.py
```

with :

`main.py`

```py
from test_lib.foo import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = foo()
    t.f_foo()
```

`foo.py`

```py
from test_lib.bar import bar

class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = bar()
    def f_foo(self):

        print(self.bar.f_bar('Foo'))
```

`bar.py`

```py
class bar:
    def f_bar(self,inp):
        return f'bar {inp}'
```

Comment: If you are running `foo.py` directly then it'll heavily depend on what directory you're in when you run it. If you're in the directory where `foo.py` is then you can see that there is, in fact, no subdirectory there called `test_lib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it right.

That's just not common to execute a random file in a package, but there's an easy way:

```
python -m test_lib.foo
```

This way the sys.path is the same as running `main.py` so it finds `test_lib`.

When running `python test_lib/foo.py` the `sys.path` contains the root of `test_lib`, in which there's no `test_lib`, leading to the `ImportError`.

Comment: ok, so that's the best way to check if the module compiles without error

Comment: Better run `pylint` on your file if you're seeking for errors, just running Python on a module will only "search" for SyntaxErrors, `pylint` can find loads of other interesting issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing foo.py from test_lib.foo which will definitely throws an ModuleNotErrorFound , this is because you are importing foo.py from test_lib.foo which obviously wrong.

See this below and you can find where are doing it wrong

```
test_lib-->foo.py-->foo.py
```

Try,

```
from test_lib import foo
```

This will might resolve the error and if not kindly check you path and then try it again.